# PHP - Upload multiple imagens

Tags: php

Ola,

Criei um código onde faço simplesmente o Upload de Multiplas imagens.

Mas não estou conseguindo inserir os valores das urls `'im/pd/'. $file_name_new;` da variável `$file_destination` no BD.

Na DB tenho..

```
User_id | img1 | img2 |
```

O que devo incluir no código para que as `urls` sejam inseridas no Banco de dados e também como salvar as imagens na pasta.

Codigo:

```
  //images function
           $ads_file = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize($_FILES['img_file']['name'][0]));  

           if(!empty($ads_file)) {

               $files = $_FILES['img_file'];
               $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

               foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {

                   $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
                   $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
                   $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

                   $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
                   $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

                   if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {

                        if($file_error === 0) {

                           if($file_size <= 4097152) {

                               $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                               $file_destination = 'im/pd/'. $file_name_new;

                               $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
                               //define o caminho para o folder e para DB

                           } else {
                              $errors[] = "
                              <div class='alert warning'>
                                  <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
                                  <strong><i class='fas fa-file-excel'></i></strong> Esta imagem é demasiado grande.
                              </div>";                               
                           }

                        } else {
                              $errors[] = "
                              <div class='alert warning'>
                                  <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
                                  <strong><i class='fas fa-plug'></i></strong> Falha ao efetuar o upload. Tente novamente...
                              </div>";   
                        }

                   } else {
                         $errors[] = "
                         <div class='alert warning'>
                              <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
                              <strong><i class='fas fa-file-excel'></i></strong> Ficheiro desconhecido, tente outro.
                         </div>";  
                   }
               }

          }
```

---

**Novo Erro**

Usei as variaveis que me deu em relação a

```
 $praBanco .=" '".$file_destination."', ";

 for ($x = 1; $x <=$quantColunas; $x++) {
   $colunas.=" ads_image_".$x." = ";
}                   
$praBanco = substr($praBanco,0,-1); 
$colunas = substr($colunas,0,-1);
```

$colunas e $praBanco

**O problema é que...**
Ele não faz update, pois penso que algo está errado em relação a entrada no update.

```
  $smtp_process = "UPDATE public_ads SET ads_title = '$ads_title', ads_content = '$ads_content', ads_price = '$ads_price', edit_attempts = edit_attempts + 1, $colunas = '$praBanco' WHERE ads_id = '$editor_id'"; 
  $smtp_request_query = $con->query($smtp_process);
```

Mas... ele nao faz update nem mostra erros...

Penso ser em relação a isto: **$colunas = '$praBanco'**

O objetivo é que ele adicione na Database o caminho da quantidade de imagens feitas em upload. Como foi feito em INSERT, soque agora UPLOAD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A solução passa por criar uma variável `$praBanco` cujo valor vai servir de `VALUES` na declaração `INSERT`

```
$praBanco .="'".$file_destination."',";
```

Estou fazendo exemplo com a extensão do PHP `mysqli` mas você use a sua.

```
 <?php

....................
...................
if($file_size <= 4097152) {

    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
    $file_destination = 'im/pd/'. $file_name_new;

    //vai servir pro VALUES do insert                       
    $praBanco .="'".$file_destination."',";
...................
...................


 if (isset($praBanco)){  

    $conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB"); 

    //retira ultima virgula     
    $praBanco = substr($praBanco,0,-1);  

    /******* insert no banco ********/
    $sql = "INSERT INTO imagens(img1,img2) VALUES ($praBanco)";
    $qr=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
    mysqli_close($conn);

 }
?>
```

**A solução ótima seria assim;**

```
.....................................
.....................................

$files = $_FILES['img_file'];
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif');

 //numero de colunas no banco
 $colBanco=5;

 $j=0;

foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {

    $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
    $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
    $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {

         if($file_error === 0) {

            if($file_size <= 4097152) {

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'im/pd/'. $file_name_new;

                 //limita para a quantidade correspondente ao numero de colunas no banco
                 if ($j<$colBanco){
                    $praBanco .="'".$file_destination."',";
                 }
                 $j++;

                 $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
                 //define o caminho para o folder e para DB

.....................................
.....................................

     if (isset($praBanco)){
        /*****************************************************************************/
        //verificamos o numero de imagens para determinar o numero de colunas no banco.

        $quantColunas = substr_count($praBanco, ',');
        /*****************************************************************************/

        /****criamos os nomes das colunas para usar na declaração INSERT *******/
        for ($x = 1; $x <=$quantColunas; $x++) {
            $colunas.="img".$x.",";
        }
        /*****************************************************************************/


        /******* conexão ao banco - exemplo com a extensão do PHP mysqli ********/
        $conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

        /**** retira a ultima virgula *******/     
        $praBanco = substr($praBanco,0,-1); 
        $colunas = substr($colunas,0,-1);
        /***********************************/

        /******* insert no banco ********/
        $sql = "INSERT INTO imagens ($colunas) VALUES ($praBanco)";
        echo $sql;
        $qr=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
        mysqli_close($conn);

   }
```

> Neste caso só salvaria no banco no MAXIMO até a quantidade de colunas existentes

---

<sub>Conforme pedido no comentárario do AP `mas como faço agora para ele MOVER as 2 IMAGENS para a Folder?` editei a pergunta e a resposta para abranger essa situação.</sub>

### Para salvar as imagens na pasta

> basta inserir no código `move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination);`

**Situações a considerar**

1 - Todas as imagens enviadas pelo formulário

```
................
................
if ($j<$colBanco){
    $praBanco .="'".$file_destination."',";
}
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)
$j++;
...............
...............
```

2 - Somente aquelas cujo urls foram salvas no banco de dados

Insira a linha dentro da condicional

```
................
................
if ($j<$colBanco){
    $praBanco .="'".$file_destination."',";
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)
}
$j++;
...............
...............
```

Comment: Gostei, muito bom, mas como faço agora para ele MOVER as 2 IMAGENS para a Folder?

Comment: Poderia ajudar-me @Leo Caracciolo

Comment: Hey Friend... eheheh i've got one mroe question to ask u... i did a update query.... but is not updating... can you please check my code...

Comment: $smtp_process = "UPDATE public_ads SET ads_title = '$ads_title', ads_content = '$ads_content', ads_price = '$ads_price', edit_attempts = edit_attempts + 1, $colunas = '$praBanco' WHERE ads_id = '$editor_id'";
                             $smtp_request_query = $con->query($smtp_process);

Comment: @user21312321, Ask a new question and tell me here what the link in the post is. Para te mostrar como fazer através de comentário fica difícil. Faça uma nova pergunta e me diga aqui qual o link do post.

Comment: Desculpa lá.. não fui eu que respondi.
É assim, eu tenho uma parte do codigo que é exatamente igual a essa de enviar multiplas imagens, soque em vez de ser em INSERT será num UPDATE...

Comment: @user21312321, então faça uma nova pergunta postando o código que colocastes no comentário acima que lhe dou uma solução pois aqui com comentário fica difícil e ininteligível a resposta. Assim que postar a pergunta deixe um comentário aqui

Comment: Leo Caracciolo, Enviei o erro em cima **Novo Erro**, ajude sff.

Comment: @user21312321 , faça nova pergunta pra esse post não ficar confuso! Coloca o que vc tinha feito como resposta que eu edito pra ficar de acordo

Comment: Simplesmente, como fez anteriormente... Adicionar as Imagens no INSERT... soque agora em UPLOAD.. é apenas definir as variaveis dentro do UPLOAD....Consegue ajudar?

Comment: SIM, mas faça nova pergunta, não custa nada fazer né!!!!!!

Comment: Claro, esta aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291503/php-upload-errors