# Erros de upload no PHP

Tags: php

Usei as variáveis que me deu em relação a... [**pergunta anterior**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290526/php-upload-multiple-imagens/290899?noredirect=1)

```
 $praBanco .=" '".$file_destination."', ";

 for ($x = 1; $x <=$quantColunas; $x++) {
    $colunas.=" ads_image_".$x." = ";
 } 

 $praBanco = substr($praBanco,0,-1); 
 $colunas = substr($colunas,0,-1);
```

`$colunas` e `$praBanco`

O problema é que... Ele não faz update, pois penso que algo está errado em relação a entrada no update.

```
 $smtp_process = "UPDATE public_ads SET ads_title = '$ads_title', ads_content = '$ads_content', ads_price = '$ads_price', edit_attempts = edit_attempts + 1, $colunas = '$praBanco' WHERE ads_id = '$editor_id'"; 
 $smtp_request_query = $con->query($smtp_process);
```

Mas... ele nao faz update nem mostra erros...

Penso ser em relação a isto: `$colunas = '$praBanco'`

O objetivo é que ele adicione na Database o caminho das imagens feitas em upload. Como foi feito em INSERT, soque agora UPLOAD.

Comment: Como poderei efetuar a correção do Upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já tem `$colunas` e `$praBanco` pode fazer um loop e concatenar os valores respectivamente dos elementos dos arrays retornados pela função `explode` do PHP

```
$explodeColunas = explode(',', $colunas);

$explodePraBanco = explode(',', $praBanco);

for($i = 0; $i<count($explodeColunas); $i++){

    $paraUpadate .= $explodeColunas[$i]."=".$explodePraBanco[$i].",";

}

//para retirar os 3 caracteres do final da string  ,=, ( virgula sinal de igual virgula )
$paraUpadate = substr($paraUpadate,0,-3);

//agora é só colocar esse resultado na declaração UPDATE

$smtp_process = "UPDATE public_ads SET ads_title = '$ads_title', ads_content = '$ads_content', ads_price = '$ads_price', edit_attempts = edit_attempts + 1, $paraUpadate WHERE ads_id = '$editor_id'";
```

**Veja o código acima funcionando no** [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/HVxk7u) [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu erro..Ele diz que **Notice: Undefined variable: paraUpadate in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.7.9\inc\creator\class_edit_ads.php on line 210

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.7.9\inc\creator\class_edit_ads.php on line 210**

Comment: Erro foi aqui: $paraUpadate .= $explodeColunas[$i]."=".$explodePraBanco[$i].",";

Comment: Fiz testes aqui e rodou corretamente. Faz um `echo $paraUpadate` e veja se está montada corretamente

Comment: Fica assim... **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\Superfacil_v1.7.9\inc\creator\class_edit_ads.php on line 211
string(118) " ads_image_1 = ads_image_2 = ads_image_3 == 'im/pd/5ad3dd6bd58c86.55498080.jpg',= 'im/pd/5ad3dd6bd5a312.43966416.jp"**

Comment: Mas a forma de como ele guarda está errada

ads_image_1 = ads_image_2 = ads_image_3 == 'im/pd/5ad3dd6bd58c86.55498080.jpg',= 'im/pd/5ad3dd6bd5a312.43966416.jp"

Comment: Objetivo é enviar 1 ou 3 ficheiros... 1 parece que envia bem, agora os 2 restantes nao.. os "==" estão... a interferir..

Comment: Ok, já corrigi... Já deu, mas continua é a aparecer Undefined offset: 1 /2/3....

Comment: Você precisa declarar as variaveis para não darem erro de `Undefined variable:` Isso é primario hehehe

Comment: Claro, mas a esta hora é dificil ver, mas... Tirando o =, ele fica NULL nos campos da Base de Dados... :D e com = (dando os Undefined variable) ele resulta... e as variaveis estão definidas la em cima com $x = ''

Comment: Editei a resposta e coloquei no ideone para rodar, rodando sem erros. Nada mais posso fazer. Dai pra frente teria que ser adivinho pra saber o que você fez no seu código.